# FreeSurfer installed on Ubuntu

Tags: installation, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to install FreeSurfer on Ubutun. I follow an installation instruction online. When I walk through this step, I have a question:

```
Here is your FreeSurfer license. Place the four lines between theCUT HERE markers in a file named "license.txt" in the directory pointed toby the $FREESURFER_HOME environment variable (see the FreeSurfer documentation).
#---------------CUT HERE--------------- 
xxxxxx

xxxxx

xxxxx

xxxxx
#---------------CUT HERE---------------
```

Does that mean I have to paste the four lines into a file called "license.txt"? I actually did in this way. I paste the four lines at the end of a file called "license.txt". But when I finish all the steps and check the installation. There is an error popping up:

```
ERROR: FreeSurfer license file /home/urser/Downloads/freesurfer/license.txt not found.
```

But the license.txt is really in that fold called "freesurfer". Do I misunderstand the instruction?

Comment: What's the output of "ls -la /home/user/Downloads/freesurfer/*" (without the quotes)?

Comment: @mrunion, there are lots of files after tying your command

Comment: Is license.txt one of them? If so, what is the entire line our output for that file?

Comment: @mrunion, -rw-rw-r-- 1 user Sep 11 12:18 /home/user/Downloads/freesurfer/license~
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user Sep 11 12:28 /home/user/Downloads/freesurfer/license.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user Sep 11 12:28 /home/user/Downloads/freesurfer/license.txt~

Comment: ·@mrunion,I guess I fixed that problem. but the installation is still not ok. The new problem shows like this:

Comment: new error:   MultiRegistration::initializing Xforms (init 1 , maxres 0 , iterate 5 , epsit 0.01 ) : 

[in]=== TP 2 to TP 1 ===
         Register TP 2 ( /home/user/Downloads/freesurfer/subjects/bert/mri/orig/002.mgz )
          to      TP 1 ( /home/user/Downloads/freesurfer/subjects/bert/mri/orig/001.mgz )


   - Max Resolution used: 2
     -- gpS ( 64 , 64 , 64 )
     -- gpT ( 64 , 64 , 64 )
Killed 
Linux ubuntu 3.19.0-25-generic #26~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:16:20 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

recon-all -s bert exited with ERRORS at Fri Sep 11 12:44:54 PDT 2015

Comment: @mrunion, please see the error above. The version of my ubuntu is 14.04

Comment: I am at a loss on that issue. I don't run Ubuntu or FreeSurfer. Can you try the Ubuntu forums with that error message? Maybe someone there will know what the issue is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please follow the instructions:

### Requirements

```
sudo apt-get install tcsh
```

### Download and installation

```
cd ~
# this is the 64 bit version
wget ftp://surfer.nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/pub/dist/freesurfer/5.3.0/freesurfer-Linux-centos6_x86_64-stable-pub-v5.3.0.tar.gz
cd /usr/local/
sudo tar -xzvf ~/freesurfer-*.tar.gz
```

### Setting the environment

```
echo "FREESURFER_HOME=/usr/local/freesurfer" >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'source $FREESURFER_HOME/SetUpFreeSurfer.sh' >> ~/.bashrc
```

### Cleaning up -> this is optional

```
rm ~/freesurfer-*.tar.gz
```

### Registering your software

Now register at https://surfer.nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/registration.html and paste the license code emailed to you here, **PLEASE BE EXTRA CAREFUL WITH THIS STEP**:

```
sudo gedit /usr/local/freesurfer/license.txt
```

I am not sure whether this next step is essential, but I usually run it.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libtiff.so.{4,3}
```

### Conclusions

All in all, installing Freesurfer is not that hard, but installing it in a new linux system is surely a better option than messing with VirtualMachines in Windows. The VM that they offer in their website does not allow to run the commands in files residing in the host machine, which is the point of running a VM in the end.

[Source](http://mirko.windhoff.net/how_to/install_freesurfer_on_ubuntu)

Comment: latest uses version 6 not 5.3 see https://surfer.nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/fswiki/DownloadAndInstall

Answer (score 1):

The current freesurfer 7.2 version has some semblance of a binary installer (.deb package) that worked for me on Ubuntu 18
(https://surfer.nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/fswiki/rel7downloads).  On Windows, in lieu of running Ubuntu in a VirtualBox VM (which includes an X-server), you can use the windows subsystem for linux (WSL) to download and run the default Ubuntu image.  Then try to download and run the freesurfer .deb binary installer in Ubuntu.  With WSL 1 or 2 you can access the path to your windows home directory mounted in linux (https://surfer.nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/fswiki//FS7_wsl).  You still need to setup an X server on Windows 10 to work with freeview running in Ubuntu under WSL, but I read that should no longer be necessary with WSL in Windows 11.  Once you obtain a freesurfer license (https://surfer.nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/registration.html) then just set the environment variable FS_LICENSE to the absolute path for the license file, e.g., in your shell init file in Ubuntu (in order for freeview to run).